# cant get fancybox to work when using link in image

Tags: jquery, css, fancybox

So, I am trying to have this image show up in the fancy box view and then when u click on the image it will download a file. But! When i have the images have anchors around the img tag the fancy box effect wont work.

heres the page:

click on the check out my resume banner and it will show the 2 images of resumes. I want to be able to click on either and it will download my file. But liek i said, when i do it, fancy box wont let me click on the banner.

Comment: What do you mean "won't let me"?  Currently, you don't have any links at all, so it's hard to say what's wrong.

Comment: hmmm lemme show u real quick.  i'll add the anchor tags around teh images and the banner doesn't become clickable

Comment: You should include all relevant code within your post.  Please read this:  http://sscce.org.

Comment: Your `a` doesn't surround your banner, does it?

Comment: Oh, I see what's going on... give me a minute.

Comment: it does, i have an anchor around the banner to go to the #whichResume when clicked and then in that div i have 2 images with anchors around both images that "should" go to a document.

Comment: Yeah, it's because of how your organized your HTML.  The fancybox content should not be inside of your link.  See my answer below.

Comment: I'll look into it and check out ur answer.  Ya know, i wasn't too sure if I was using the code correctly.  Thanks for the help

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are calling `.fancybox()` on `a#linkTo`.  When Fancybox finds a link inside of an anchor you point to, it will remove the contents of your anchor (`#linkTo`) to some other location in the DOM.  This is presumably for ease of use.   In your case, you want the `#workTag` to remain in the link.  So if you remove your fancybox content (`#whichResume`) outside of your anchor, Fancybox should automatically find the content with id `#whichResume`, because your href points to it.  You don't need it to be inside of you link.

Change this:

```
<a id="linkTo" href="#whichResume">     
    <div id="workTag">       
        <div id="whichResume" style="background:white;" class="roundedCorners">     
            <a href="images/icons/document_pdf.png">
                <img src="images/resumeTHUMB/graphicResumeTHUMB.jpg" class="graphic" />
            </a>       
            <a href="images/icons/document_pdf.png">
                <img style="margin-left:50px;" src="images/resumeTHUMB/typeResumeTHUMB.jpg" class="type"/>
            </a>       
        </div>   
    </div>  
</a>
```

To this:

```
<a id="linkTo" href="#whichResume">     
    <div id="workTag"></div>  
</a>

<div id="whichResume" style="background:white;" class="roundedCorners">     
    <a href="images/icons/document_pdf.png">
        <img src="images/resumeTHUMB/graphicResumeTHUMB.jpg" class="graphic" />
    </a>       
    <a href="images/icons/document_pdf.png">
        <img style="margin-left:50px;" src="images/resumeTHUMB/typeResumeTHUMB.jpg" class="type"/>
    </a>       
</div>
```

See example here: http://jsfiddle.net/jtbowden/BTqxx/

Comment: can you explain the "You are calling .fancybox() on a#linkTo. Fancybox should automatically find the content with id #whichResume. You don't need it to be inside of you link. If you pull it out, your link should remain intact." are you talking about my script tags that have "$("a#linkTo").fancybox();"? Do I not need this?

Comment: Sorry, it's not clear I know...  I am talking about the HTML structure.  If you point fancybox to a link (like `#linkTo`), with another link inside it, it takes the contents and moves them.  Because your `workTag` is also inside the link, it moves it as well, which you don't want to happen.  Instead, you can simply move your fancybox content yourself, and as long as the ID matches the href hash, fancybox will do the right thing.  It looks like you tried this and it worked on your page.

Comment: It does work! I do appreciate the time you spent to help me out.  Thank you!

Answer (score 0):

I would be nice if you could post some example code how you tried to get it working.

Can't you do something like:

```
$(function(){
   $("#a#linkTo").click(function(){
     $("whichResume").fancybox();
   });
});
```

And the code of the #whichResume div

```
<a href="images/resumeTHUMB/graphicResumeTHUMB.jpg">
<img class="graphic" src="images/resumeTHUMB/graphicResumeTHUMB.jpg">
</a>
<a href="images/resumeTHUMB/typeResumeTHUMB.jpg">
<img class="type" src="images/resumeTHUMB/typeResumeTHUMB.jpg" style="margin-left:50px;">
</a>
```

I did not tested it, would be a lot of easier if you post the example code here.

Also give #whichResume a default display:none, for the users who have javascript disabled (like me).

Comment: Thanks, i went ahead to fix the display.  I need to go through my site with java disable and see whats going on